# Scanner scanned value incomplete

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am currently developing a verification system on C#.

I have a datagridview which allow user to scan barcode into it and verify using regex.

Now the problem:

I have a barcode value with RS GS and EOT, so the scanned value will looks different in c#

```
RS \u001e 
GS \u001d 
EOT \u0004
```

When i try to scan it with scanner the value only remain RS while GS and EOT is gone, but i tried to scan it to notepad++ and using copy paste it back to the input field it only works.

C#.net have some difficulty trying to read scanner scanned value?

Sample value:

in notepad ++

[image]

in c# string scanned value:

> [)>\u001e99888887777766665555444433333\u001e

in c# string pasted value from notepad++:

> [)>\u001e99\u001d88888\u001d77777\u001d6666\u001d5555\u001d4444\u001d33333\u001e\u0004

The GS and EOT is missing (the moment i scan it i realise it is missing in the input field)

byte[ ] of scanned value:

> [0]: 91
>   [1]: 41
>   [2]: 62
>   [3]: 30
>   [4]: 57
>   [5]: 57
>   [6]: 56
>   [7]: 56
>   [8]: 56
>   [9]: 56
>   [10]: 56
>   [11]: 55
>   [12]: 55
>   [13]: 55
>   [14]: 55
>   [15]: 55
>   [16]: 54
>   [17]: 54
>   [18]: 54
>   [19]: 54
>   [20]: 53
>   [21]: 53
>   [22]: 53
>   [23]: 53
>   [24]: 52
>   [25]: 52
>   [26]: 52
>   [27]: 52
>   [28]: 51
>   [29]: 51
>   [30]: 51
>   [31]: 51
>   [32]: 51
>   [33]: 30

byte[ ] of pasted value from notepad++:

> [0]: 91
>   [1]: 41
>   [2]: 62
>   [3]: 30
>   [4]: 57
>   [5]: 57
>   [6]: 29
>   [7]: 56
>   [8]: 56
>   [9]: 56
>   [10]: 56
>   [11]: 56
>   [12]: 29
>   [13]: 55
>   [14]: 55
>   [15]: 55
>   [16]: 55
>   [17]: 55
>   [18]: 29
>   [19]: 54
>   [20]: 54
>   [21]: 54
>   [22]: 54
>   [23]: 29
>   [24]: 53
>   [25]: 53
>   [26]: 53
>   [27]: 53
>   [28]: 29
>   [29]: 52
>   [30]: 52
>   [31]: 52
>   [32]: 52
>   [33]: 29
>   [34]: 51
>   [35]: 51
>   [36]: 51
>   [37]: 51
>   [38]: 51
>   [39]: 30
>   [40]: 4

Comment: Can you convert your string to a `byte[]` in C# and show us what is there?

Comment: Update your question, don't post as a comment.

Comment: @Enigmativity done add in the byte[ ] info on question

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? You said C# does not do what you expect, but we don't have a single line of code we could look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found myself the solution.

C#.NET is blocking the value of Control Characters (GS, RS and EOT etc..)

In order to force it to read the value, all I can do is reading user key press and if the input equals to the control characters. i will then programmically add in the ASCII value of the control characters:

```
RS \u001e
GS \u001d
EOT \u0004
```

The code will be like something like this:

```
private void txtScanInput_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int i = this.txtScanInput.SelectionStart;
        switch ((int)(e.KeyChar))
        {
        case 4: //EOT
            this.txtScanInput.Text = this.txtScanInput.Text.Insert(this.txtScanInput.SelectionStart, "\u0004");
            this.txtScanInput.SelectionStart = i + 6;
            e.Handled = true;
            break;

        case 29: //GS
            this.txtScanInput.Text = this.txtScanInput.Text.Insert(this.txtScanInput.SelectionStart, "\u001d");
            this.txtScanInput.SelectionStart = i + 6;
            e.Handled = true;
            break;

        case 30: //RS
            this.txtScanInput.Text = this.txtScanInput.Text.Insert(this.txtScanInput.SelectionStart, "\u001e");
            this.txtScanInput.SelectionStart = i + 6;
            e.Handled = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(ex);
        MessageBox.Show(MessageConstants.APPLICATION_ERROR + "\n[" + ex.Message + "]\n[" + ex.InnerException + "]\n" + AppUtil.getLatestErrorDAL(),
            MessageConstants.SYSTEM_NAME + " - txtScanInput_KeyPress");
    }
}
```